# Websockets sending garbage to server

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

I have created a WebSockets connection from my website to my home server running a python script listening on port 3000. I can connect to the server just fine as the server logs that a client has connected when I load my page. However each time I connect to the server, the server automatically fires my servers receivedMessage() function and prints out a bunch of garbage regarding the connection. The servers logs are below:

```
A new client has connected
Message Received:  GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [Insert host name and port here]
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 3DUmKD70X9p19IpLPjS2jg==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

The snippet of code to connect to the server is simple enough:

```
var theSocket = new WebSocket("ws://[insert host name]:3000");

    theSocket.onopen = function() {
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        theSocket.send("blah");
        alert("SENT");
     };
```

Also the alert box never shows up when the above script is run. What is causing all the connection details to print and how do I get it to send a simple string and successfully pop up the alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely that your WebSocket is never transitioning from CONNECTING to OPEN and thus never calling your onopen function. You need to make sure your python script is going through the [Web Socket Handshake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers) on the server side.

Comment: The fact that my javascript console just printed out "WebSocket connection to 'ws://{HOSTNAME]:3000/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled' makes me think you are correct.

Comment: Just trying to understand - above still doesn't answer why the WS server is printing garbage when even the connection hasn't been successful. Is it some default WS behavior.

Comment: Correct, if you look at the linked article in the first section, you can see that the websocket client will send a "standard" http get request, which is what Aimee is seeing in their server print. Its hard to say more about it without the python server's code.