# Why is Websocket sending garbage along with payload?

Tags: c#, angular, sockets, websocket, tcplistener

Before posting the question I took at look at this one: [Websockets sending garbage to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063111/websockets-sending-garbage-to-server)

The issue, it seems, in the above question is that the socket wasn't transitioning to OPEN.

In my case I make sure state is OPEN and then send data. I am able to get data from web to my desktop app but it always has some garbage data right before the actual payload.

Why is that?

here is the client code:

```
  socketOpenHandler = (event) => { 
    // if socket is open
    if(event.target.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      this._$socket.next({code: 0, message: 'success'}); 
    }
  }

  connect(url : string) : Observable<SocketResponse> {
    try {
      this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
      this.socket.onopen = this.socketOpenHandler;
      this.socket.onclose = this.socketDisconnectHanlder;
      this.socket.onerror = this.socketErrorHanlder;
      this.socket.onmessage = this.socketMessageHandler;

      return this._$socket;

    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }        
  }
```

and here is the server code

```
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;
                    while (client.Available < 3) ; // match against "get"

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];
                    stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.Available);
                    string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                    Console.WriteLine($"++data:{s}");
                   ... rest of code ...
                }
             }
```

This is what I am sending:

```
          PrintData:
            [
              {
                text: "   Cx: lastname, firstname    M999",
                options: {}
              },
            ... rest of payload ...
```

This is what I am getting (only the last line is valid and the rest is simply garbage):

```
?H???Th???&i??N??To??L??????G??
??O??2G?T?TR???V????U?K??V@?R??C??V??O??TI?I??T?
??C?T??V??H??L??@??A??D??V??Vk??F??Oe??TI?I??T?
??C?T??V??C??Vt?O??V??V??V??V`?V??V??F??V?H??L]?Z]??^??L??TI?I??T??C?:O??T??
??C?T??V??%v??V??/j??V??u??V?2??Vv??V??"??V?H??L]?Z]??^??L?V??F??V??V??F??V??V??V??V??D??TI?I??T?
??C?T??%??G??V??V??V??V??F??V??E??V??Z??O????T@?j???[??TR???$CµM??Z??O????[??TR???7U??I??U??U?J??Z??O????[??TR???<I??G??V?H??L]?Z]??^??L??V`?C??$d??E??F??C??TI?I??T?
??JuVR??_??TI?I??T?V
??C?T??V?R???Ve??O????V?H??L]?Z]??^??L???Z??O????[??TR???V??G±L??D??[??F??T
?R??T??V?I???F??TI?I??T?
??C?T??V??4GoE??V??T
?J??L?B??{?
@!    Cx: lastname, firstname    M999
```

Web app written in Angular and desktop in C# using TcpListener.

Comment: The encoding is wrong with the tool you are using to see the data.  I believe you would be getting an exception if the data was being transmitter improperly.  So I think it is just a viewing issue.

Comment: @jdwend, I am not using any tool. why would you assume that?

Comment: How are you displaying the data?  The output is fro a tool!!!

Comment: this is from console. I am simply doing a Console.WriteLine(...). If encoding was incorrect then why is the actual payload i am sending correct but there is some garbage before that?

Comment: The console output does not include encoding.  Save to a file and then open with a tool that will properly encode the text.

Comment: i have done that already and tried different encoding. All seems garbage. But would you actually know why would websocket send all this along with my payload?

Comment: The websocket is sending bytes.  Not strings with encoding.

Comment: See following to set the output encoding for the console : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-how-to-change-the-output-encoding-scheme-of-the-console/

Comment: ok so I started reading up on the RFC document here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.1 and if I am not wrong this data is actually frame data. is this correct?

Comment: Frame data is bytes with no explicit encoding.  It is up to the viewer on receiving end to apply the encoding.  Eight bit encoding in general the bytes 0x00 to 0x7F are the same for all encoding methods.  The bytes 0x80 to 0xFF are mapped to different Unicode characters depending on the encoding.  So encoding save number of bytes so instead of sending two byte unicode character only one byte is sent.  but the the sending and receiving have to be consistent in the encoding used.